# What is the correct Lewis structure of NH3O?

Tags: lewis-structure

> Choose the most appropriate Lewis structure for $\ce{NH3O}$ among the two:
>
> [image: NH2-OH] and [image]

The oxygen in the second case has 3 nonbonding pairs around it.

I chose the first as an answer, yet the second seems to be the correct one. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: The second structure does exist in the crystalline phase. I know crystals that conceive the second structure. One such crystal could be Hydroxylammonium 5-oxo-4,5-dihydrotetrazol-1-ide azane oxide. It can be downloaded from CSD (https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/?), with identifier YEKJEF (CSD reference). Also, check, the reference, D.Fischer, T.M.Klapotke, J.Stierstorfer, Propellants,Explos.,Pyrotech. (2012), 37, 156, doi:10.1002/prep.201100108

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Technically, both the structures $\ce{H2N-OH}$ and $\ce{H3N\bond{->}O}$ may exist. However, in reality hydrogen atom is rather prone to migration and the second structure is not favorable. So, for a compound with composition $\ce{NH3O}$, the correct structure would be $\ce{H2N-OH}$. The structure of second type is stable for compound $\ce{NOF3}$ and may be observed for amine oxides like $\ce{(C2H5)3N\bond{->}O}$ or pyridine *N*-oxide.

Why $\ce{H2N-OH}$  and not $\ce{H3N\bond{->}O}$? One  can come with several explanations for that, but I would like to focus on one: charge distribution. In $\ce{H3N\bond{->}O}$, the nitrogen has to carry a formal positive (and actually very real) charge, while for $\ce{H2N-OH}$, the structure has no formal charges. Still, according to some sources<sup>[1]</sup> up to 20% of hydroxylamine in water exists as ammonia oxide $\ce{H3N\bond{->}O}$, probably, due to stabilization by hydrogen bonds.

Somewhat similar uncertainty may be found for phosphorus compounds (like hypophosphorous acid) and sulfur compounds (like sulfinic acids).

---

1. Kirby, A. J.; Davies, J. E.; Fox, D. J.; Hodgson, D. R. W.; Goeta, A. E.; Lima, M. F.; Priebe, J. P.; Santaballa, J. A.; Nome, F. Ammonia oxide makes up some 20% of an aqueous solution of hydroxylamine. *Chem. Commun.* **2010,** *46* (8), 1302. [DOI: 10.1039/b923742a](https://doi.org/10.1039/b923742a).

Comment: So basically the first structure is the most probable one and the teacher is wrong?

Comment: @HasanSaad Pretty much. Point to this article if needed.  http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/22/2/10.1063/1.1740030